# Jquery get values from select boxes and make AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple select boxes, where I want to get the value of each selected option and make an AJAX call based on the selected options. How can I achieve that?

I have this so far:

```
$('select[name="restaurant_chosen"]').on('change', function() {
    var restaurant_id = $(this).val();
});

$('select[name="date_chosen"]').on('change', function() {
    var date_chosen = $(this).val();
});

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/api/' + restaurant_id + '/' + date_chosen +
   success: function(data) {
     console.log(data)
   }, 
   error: function(data){
    console.log('error')
  }
 });
```

the 2 variables `restaurant_id` and `date_chosen` I get the error `not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a very basic oops called variable access scope. You have declared the variables inside the change function and tying to access in ajax call. make them global to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function sendToServer(values, onSuccess, onError){

  var restaurant_id, date_chosen;
  
  //here fill restaurant_id and date_chosen  using values
  
  $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/api/' + restaurant_id + '/' + date_chosen, //replace the plus by a comma
     success: function(data) {
       onSuccess(data);
     }, 
     error: function(data){
      onSuccess(data);
    }
   });
   
}


$('select').on('change', function() {
  var values = [];
  $('select').each(function(index){        
    v = $(this).val();     
    n = $(this).attr("name");
    values.push( {"name":n, "value":v} );  
  });

  console.log("values: ", values);
  
  sendToServer(values, 
    function(data){
       console.log(data);
    }, 
    function(data){
      console.log('error', data);
    }
  );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="brand">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<select name="color">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

And that is how it should be. You're declaring your variable within a private function context, which you cannot (and must not) access from the outside.

Simple solution, move the declaration of your two variable out of the `onchange` event handlers (make it more global).

```
var restaurant_id;
    date_chosen;

$('select[name="date_chosen"]').on('change', function() {
   date_chosen = $(this).val(); // skip the var here
});
```